# Any way to speed up runs?

Tags: python

Im currently trying to do a monte carlo simulation, the problem is its taking quite a while to run 100,000 runs or more when Im told it shouldnt take very long.

Heres my code:

```
runs = 10000

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import uniform
import seaborn as sns
import pandas 

def steadystate():
    p=0.88
    Cout=4700000000
    LambdaAER=0.72
    Vol=44.5
    Depo=0.42
    Uptime=0.1
    Effic=0.38
    Recirc=4.3
    x = random.randint(86900000,2230000000000)
    conc = ((p*Cout*LambdaAER)+(x/Vol))/(LambdaAER+Depo+(Uptime*Effic*Recirc))
    return conc

x = 0
while x < runs:
    #results = steadystate (Faster)
    results = np.array([steadystate() for _ in range(1000)])
    print(results)
    x+=1
    
ax = sns.distplot(results,
                  bins=100,
                  kde=True,
                  color='skyblue',
                  hist_kws={"linewidth": 15,'alpha':1})
ax.set(xlabel='Uniform Distribution ', ylabel='Frequency')
```

Im fairly new at python so Im unsure of where to optimize my code. Any help or suggestions would be much appreaciated.

Comment: What happens if you omit `print(results)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it just skips the printing, still takes a significant amount of time to plot the graph.

Comment: I thought the simulation takes too much time. Now you are saying that plotting the graph takes too much time. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: `np.array([steadystate() for _ in range(1000)])` is a loop that runs 1000 times, hence your'e `steadystate()`10000*1000 or 10,000,000 times

Comment: @CodeKorn: Computers can do 10M units of work pretty fast, if you're close enough to the metal, the OP just didn't really let `numpy` help them.

Comment: You're also not appending `results` anywhere, so when the loop is done you only have the last result

Comment: @ShadowRanger OP thought he was running 100,000 times, realizing that it's running 100 times more than that might let him know why "its taking quite a while to run"

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually benefiting from `numpy` here, because you produce each value one at a time, doing all the math for that one value, then producing the array from the results. Work with arrays from the get-go, and do all the work on all elements in bulk to derive the benefits of vectorization:

```
import numpy.random

def steadystate(count):  # Receive desired number of values for bulk generation
    p=0.88
    Cout=4700000000
    LambdaAER=0.72
    Vol=44.5
    Depo=0.42
    Uptime=0.1
    Effic=0.38
    Recirc=4.3
    x = numpy.random.randint(86900000, 2230000000000, count)  # Make array of count values all at once

    # Perform all the math in bulk
    conc = ((p*Cout*LambdaAER)+(x/Vol))/(LambdaAER+Depo+(Uptime*Effic*Recirc))
    return conc

x = 0
while x < runs:
    results = steadystate(1000)  # Just call with number of desired items
    print(results)
    x+=1
```

Note that this code matches your original code by replacing `results` each time, rather than accumulating results. I'm not clear on what you what to do instead, so this is just doing the (probably) wrong thing much faster.

Comment: I think I wasnt clear in my original description, but thanks for letting me know that 'results = np.array([steadystate() for _ in range(1000)])' actually multiplied my original 'runs' count. But using your revised code, it just returns results that arent in an array anymore which I need for plotting the results.

Comment: @bowlcutinmatrix: The updated code returns an array. Note the change in `steadystate`; `x` is a whole array of randomly chosen values, and the various operations are vectorized over it, returning a new array that is the result of all those manipulations.

Comment: [Example of it working just fine, producing an array.](https://tio.run/##VZFNT8MwDIbv/RWWdkm7qftoYQOpBwS7IJAQEtyz1mXR2iRK3bH@@pK62wBfktd2HD@27WhvdNL3qrbGEei2tl3spC5MHQQFltAQyqJrSBKK3LSawnuACbxjjuqIUGCjHBbDwx06MCUcZdViA6VxsGurA3yhRidJGR2AN5st4s2Gr4@mpSxdL87GvhdZ7wr5sH33aesVuz5NlaVpfMPiCa3xoXQMfVhSNXq9ZLktS5V7lYz1fY/K5VkaJyxPkP3j40NpEpvbO25gBqtVsrjaDEbeAfdVHhCkc7IbENl/AZVVBZLA6BwD/mcCb@g8fs0h2iPUkvagNM@DU3Kf7bsRwkbDEKIrdTgVp7kHDsO5uDqnA/RUjLARQ0YjWxhyOYfUOs1Vg8Bh01bU@PJ/V7f0QEzy3DYE@dDZt/Jd/e7tsklFWDeBdcNkqLMozgXDGVxuff8D "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

About 70% of the time you are losing is with the creation of the random numbers.
The question is whether you need each time random numbers? Would it be sufficient may be to generate the random matrix just once and reuse it.

However, the code is pretty quick isn't it. Except the drawing part this par took for one iteration just 1.2 ms.

```
%timeit results = np.array([steadystate() for _ in range(1000)])
1.24 ms ± 3.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Are there any other methods that would be faster for plotting the results? @mike

Comment: @bowlcutinmatrix I wouldn't know unfortunately.